# Does Font Awesome's suggestion to use <i> tags affect SEO?

Tags: html, validation, seo, font-awesome

We use [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io)  for most of our sites and in the examples it is suggested to use an `<i>` tag in the interests of "brevity" (it does also point out that `<span>` tag are the correct way of doing things, and I tend to agree).

I was curious as to whether or not this could have an impact on SEO. I am aware that validators (such as [Nibbler](http://nibbler.silktide.com/)) will throw up an error for the use of these tags, but I'm not sure if these warnings are anything to be concerned over or not.

Comment: Nothing wrong with `<i>` (or `<em>`) when they include semantic meaning (eg., for `<i>` it is a title – most style guides use italics). This is why those (and similar tags) were "un-deprecated" in HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Font Awesome on my sites and I wondered the same thing as well. Upon research, I discovered that using Font Awesome does not impact your SEO ranking or results. I have also run experiments and haven't noticed any change in SEO ranking upon using Font Awesome vs. plain CSS. No need to concern yourself!